# VB.Net show/hide buttons depending on variable value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, variables, button

I am trying to manage the visibility of a button depending of the value of a variable.
I have got an app with 2 sections: Haulier and Customer.

When the Haulier Logs in they have the privilege to view the Customer Section by clicking on a button called View. This takes them to the Customer Section. I need to display a button to allow them to get back to the Haulier Section. This button is not visible when the Customer is logged in.

I have got a variable called admin.
When the View button is clicked the variable is assigned 1
When the customer section loads it checks the value of the variable and decides whether to show or hide the button depending on the value of the variable.

If I open the app and log in as a Customer and close the app it works fine.
If I open the app and log in as a Haulier and close the app it works fine.
If I try to log in to both sections (either way) in the same session without closing the app, it does not work.

The code spans over about 6 pages, which makes it too complicated to post. I have been trying to fix this for hours now and I simply have no clue as to why it is not working.

Could someone please tell me how I can fix this?

Update with some code:

The global variable is admin which is stored in a module

```
    Public admin As Integer
```

On the Customer Section page load the code is as follows:

```
    Label3.Text = jkpadmin
    If jkpadmin = 1 Then
        btn_backjkpadmin.Show()
    Else
        btn_backjkpadmin.Hide()
    End If
```

On the Haulier Section page to View Button code is as follows:

```
    jkpadmin = 1
    Me.Hide()
    frm_3custjkphome.Show()
```

The variable does not seem to be updating. It works when these sections are used separately but when one is used after the other it does not work?

Update with more explanation:

If I go into the Customer section first the button should not display on page load (works as expected)

And then close it

If I go into the Haulier section first and click the View button to go to the customer section the button should display (works as expected)

If I go into the Customer section first its fine, if I then go to the Haulier section after without closing and click on the View button to go to customer section the button does not display (it should)

If I go into the Haulier section first its fine, if I then go to the Customer section after without closing the button is displayed (it shouldn't be)

Comment: Winforms? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight? Modern UI?

Comment: Its just a stand alone application. Visual Studio 2012 with vb.net

Comment: A standalone application can be almost all of the above UI platform nowadays, please be precise.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. I am making a project with a bunch of forms in it that runs like software.

Comment: I'm gonna guess you are using Winforms then. I'll add it as a tag to your question.

Comment: Yeah if you say so. Thanks. Have you got any answers regarding my question?

Comment: I'm afraid it's too broad in its actual form. There could be a lot of different ways to achieve what you want and hardly any way to tell which one would be the best in your precise scenario. IMHO you should just choose the path you think is appropriate first, and if you encounter any issues from there it will be easier for you to get help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried that. I have spent all day working on different solutions to fix this. Asking a question has been my last resort because I am completely stuck.

Comment: Then I suggest you try making a scaled down project whose purpose is to experiment on showing / hiding a button depending on a variable value. This will help you narrowing down and understanding the problem and likely give you an important clue on how to proceed in your main app. Plus, it will be easier to seek help on the sized-down code, should you need any.

Comment: That would be ideal, however I have only got 3 weeks left to finish this project and I still have a report to finish. So time is of the essence.

Comment: @CaraRichardson Your code is incomplete. You need to show the manipulation of `jkpadmin`.

Comment: What do you mean "the manipulation of jkpadmin"?

Comment: @CaraRichardson you said you spent all day working on different solutions without any success. Why can't you spare 15 minutes to set up a small working project?

Comment: Because this problem affects other things in my project and other things affect this problem. Its all linked. My project consists of 33 forms that is a booking system with various different types of functionality and database queries. This is simple one small problem within a big system.

Comment: @CaraRichardson then I'm sorry but there is absolutely NO WAY anyone on SO can help you. What you are looking for here isn't an answer, you want help to investigate on where the actual problem is within your full application scope. There's no way to tell without being able to run a debugging session, let alone give you the appropriate solution that wouldn't make everything else falls apart. Any successful attempt to do so would be a very wild guess.

Comment: well unfortunately for you. By taking the advice of other users helpful comments and having a play around with it. I have managed to fix it :) I will add the answer in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem. It's in this statement:

> When the customer section **loads** it checks the value of the variable and decides whether to show or hide the button depending on the value of the variable.

(emphasis mine)

You may show and hide a form instance many times, but *it only loads once*. Move that logic to the Form's `Activated` event instead, and you'll be fine.

Comment: That was a great idea, but unfortunately it didn't work. I still have the same problem.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post so that it suggests using the `Activated` event instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all the helpful comments. I have used these and managed to fix my problem.

I put the following code on page activated instead of page load

```
    If jkpadmin = 1 Then
        btn_backjkpadmin.Show()
    Else
        btn_backjkpadmin.Hide()
    End If
```

And reset the variable to 0 on a button that the haulier cannot access (only the customer)

I understand that this is a very specific problem. But that you to those of you that have helped. It is really appreciated :)

Comment: Joel Coehoorn had already provided that answer, you shouldn't copy it.

Comment: Now that is just silly. If you read Joel's answer he says "forms shown event" whereas I put it on the forms ACTIVATED event. I tried to put it on the shown event and it didn't work but I put it on activated by chance and it worked.

Comment: Yet that's still the answer you marked as accepted. :) Besides, the answer was that the event originaly used executed only once. The fact that he got mixed up between `Shown` and `Activated` doesn't justify adding a brand new answer, IMHO. I took the liberty to edit his answer.

Comment: Right now you are just being rude! And making me look stupid. So you can take your pathetic comments and "edits" and keep them to yourself. This is supposed to be a website where people can ask for help and receive helpful answers from experts. The fact that you are posting nothing helpful is probably putting off other users that now wont ask because of people like you. I have my answer and I have better things to do. Goodbye @Crono

Comment: Allow me to give you a bit of perspective here: First, I tried figuring out which UI platform you were working on. Somehow you couldn't answer, so I had to make a guess out of other questions you asked on SO. I edited your question and added the Winforms tag, so that it would attract developers who specializes in it. Then when you asked if I could help, I explained as nicely and clearly as I could that, as it was by then, your question was too broad. When you finally added some code, I attempted to answer.

Comment: The fact that you weren't even using the global variable you declared seemed suspect enough to be the actual problem. Somehow you just happened to name it differently for the question (why didn't you named it differently in the WHOLE question then???), hoping to make it "easier" to understand. When Joel attempted to answer I figured that had to be the answer, but you said it wasn't. Seeing how complicated your scenario was, I suggested that you create a smaller project to try out the mechanics you want and see what goes wrong. To that, you said there wasn't enough time.

Comment: And FINALLY, it turned out Joel was right all along on the problem being that your code only executed once. So quite frankly, I think it's quite unfair of you to say I'm being rude and unhelpful. In fact, I believe I've been very patient, polite and willing to help, given how little effort you were willing to put on making yourself clear and trying out things. That being said, I would suggest that next time, you try to better expose what the problem is and provide the pertinent details (UI platform is no small detail), rather than making the community look for it.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @VincentVanDenBerghe It's not additional information - it attempts to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of the variable `admin`? If it is a global variable that could be causing you problems depending on where it is set and how it is refreshed.

Additionally, why do you have this `admin` variable at all that appears to exist separately from the user object? Shouldn't you have something like this:

```
'Very basic customer setup
Class Customer
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Type() As CustomerType
        Get
            Return m_Type
        End Get
        Set
            m_Type = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Type As CustomerType

    Public Sub New(id As Integer)
        'Load customer data
        Name = "Test User"
        Type = CustomerType.Admin
    End Sub
End Class

'Customer type
Enum CustomerType
    User
    Admin
End Enum

'Very basic usage
Public Class Code
    Public Sub New()
        Dim customer__1 As Customer = Customer.Load(32)
        button.Visible = customer__1.Type = CustomerType.Admin
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I updated it to VB.NET the conversion wasn't saved in my clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand it. I have no clue how to fit your code into my application. As the problem spans over numerous pages with database connections. Where would these new classes go?

Comment: You would have to post your code. I wrote a sample since your question is missing code to work with. The basics of what I'm getting at is that you should be storing your customer type in the same object as the rest of the Customer information. Allowing you to ensure it is being updated correctly. The problem you're having sounds like a global var is being set, but not updated. Storing the admin flag in a separate location leads to bugs like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Do you ever reset the value of the variable back to 0 or something else or change it from 1 to something. Once it is set to one, does it stay there? Where in your code are you changing it based on the logged in user?

Comment: I will update the question with a further explanation. Thanks for your help.